# Init.d script to systemd problem with parameters

Tags: linux, systemd

I am trying to upgrade my init.d script called "myService" to systemd .The init.d script has 1 parameter which decides what to do, with the following switch case:

```sh
case "$choice" in 
    "start")
        # starts service logic here
    "stop") 
        # stops service logic here
    "filter") 
        # runs some .sh file from our PC
esac
```

In order to upgrade to systemd I create `myService.service` file in systemd and set in the properties of the file on ExecuteStart and ExecuteStop to execute the init.d file with parameter start or stop,now I can do : `systemctl start myService.service` ,however if I want to invoke the `filter` option I am not allowed to do `systemctl filter myService`.service since "filter" is not valid option for systemctl .Any suggestions how can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

This scheme does not fit within [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd) responsibilities as a service manager, such as (but not limited to):

- running services (e.g. starting, stopping, etc.)
- the configuration of the above (e.g. which system level to run in)
- providing information on the status of a service
- declaring the dependencies and the handling between the various services

Although you did not provide information on the implementation of the service, it seems that the `filter` mode is an application/server specific action. Moreover, it's not clearly described what happens when the service is stopped and `filter` is issued.

So, keeping in mind the separation of concerns, I'd suggest using systemd to control the start and stop of your service, but use whatever IPC ([D-Bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/), [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), [signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), etc.) that service is using to trigger the `filter` operation.